# PHP error finding database when trying to connect to it with mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I am reviewing my old work and have started to change the mysql syntax to mysqli however I am having issues trying to connect to my database. It throws the following error: No database selected.

This is my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db1");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your db name is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, probably you are giving a database name that is wrong, check if that database actually exists.

Comment: I double checked my database name and its definitely right. It works fine with the mysql_connect() function but for some reason its not working with mysqli_connect()

Comment: it seems me to that there is somewhere in another part of the code you are creating another database connection that is over riding this present database connection, and that code has wrong database name, check that possibility once.